# Find perimeter of trapezium without trigonometry

Tags: geometry

I have tried drawing heights,diagonals and some auxiliar trazes but I have not reached something concrete.

[image]

The development must be without trig. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Are the angles $55^{\circ}$ and $80^{\circ}$? They certainly don't look like $55^{\circ}$ and $80^{\circ}$ in the picture ...

Comment: You are given angles..... and not allowed to use Trigonometry?

Comment: Have you used the hight?

Comment: @MattiP. In fact it is not possible for the angles and lengths to be as given, since $\angle A+\angle D<180^\circ$ implies $AD>BC$.

Comment: It looks like it could be a flaw in the diagram.  B and C look like they could be 55 and 80 degrees respectively.

Comment: Yes @MatthewDaly was my mistake.

Comment: I doubt this is possible without trigonometry as well. $\sin 55º$ is not a rational multiple of $\sin 30º$ or $\sin 45º$, which have constructible values, even considering double angles and half angles. You could have $\sin 55º = \sin(30º/3 + 45º)$ but then you would have to solve a nasty cubic to find $\sin 10º$.

Answer (score 1):

*Revised* Hint:

The parallel to $CD$ through $A$ meets $BC$ in $E$.  We only need to consider the triangle $BEA$.  As the angle at $D$ is $45^\circ$, we'll find via Pythagoras easily that 
$$a^2+b^2-ab\sqrt2=49.$$
(That's actually the Law of Cos in disguise.)
Hence we need either $a$ and $b$ or $ab$ to determine the circumference.

Now I strongly doubt that this will be possible without trigonometry, because there's nothing "special" about the particular angles $55^\circ$ and $80^\circ$, except their sum is $135^\circ$.  Cheating we'll find that $ab=98\cos(\pi/18)\cos(7\pi/18)$, but I see no way to produce the value of $ab$ without trigs.

*Old* Hint: Prolong $BA$ over $A$ and $CD$ over $D$, they meet in $F$.  Key observation is that the angle at $F$ is $45^\circ$.  Use the  intercept theorem to calculate  $FD$ in terms of $b$ and $FA$ in terms of $a$. Now draw the height in $B$ and use Pythagoras cleverly.

Comment: Thanks, corrected.